# Message: "CSRF token mismatch.", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException",…}

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5, csrf, csrf-token

I am A PHP developer and currently moving towards Laravel framework as per my task I have to complete the realtime table using ajax but I am sticking with an error which is CSRF token mismatch error please help me to resolve the error I am posting shortcode only

**JAVA Script**

```
<script>

 function getMessage() {
        $.ajax({
           //var data = {"_token": $('#token').val()},
           type:'POST',
           url:'/getMsg',
           headers: {'XSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')},
           success:function(data) {
              $("#msg").html(data.msg);
           }
           
        });
        
     }
    
  </script>
```

**Route Path**

```
Route::post('/getMsg','CustomerSearchController@doAjaxTest');
```

**Controller code**

```
public function doAjaxTest(){
    $msg = "<b>Message over ajax This test is Successful</b>.";
    return response()->json(array('msg'=> $msg), 200);
}
```

***HTML CODE***

```
<center>
 
 <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = '<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>'>
 <table>
 <tr>
 
 <td><label>Enter Place Name</label></td>
 <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="placename" name="placename" placeholder="Name Of Place"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
 <input type="submit" value="Get Message" onclick="getMessage()" />
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>

 <br>
 <!--
 <div class="panel panel-default table-responsive">
            <div id="dataTag"><b>All the Details according to department will be displayed</b></div>
            
      </div>
 -->
 <div id = 'msg'>This message will be replaced using Ajax. 
     Click the button to replace the message.</div>
  </center>
```

I don't know why it is showing me CSRF token mismatch when headers contain tokens
once solved i can have some realtime action please help out

Comment: what is XSRF-TOKEN in your code? Does this $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') return the token? Why 'content' not 'value'?
Send correct data in your ajax: $.ajax({data: {_token: $('input[name=_token]').val(), placename: $('input[name=placename]').val()}, type: 'post', url: '...', success: function() {...}}. Double check with debugger or console.log() if data you are sending is ok, so if it has both placename and _token.

Comment: please rewrite the above code so my basics can be cleared

Answer (score 4):

make sure that you have the meta tag in your head of the view:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Then you can initialize it just once after loading the jQuery library, add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
</script>
```

Try with solution

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem. i changed **APP_NAME** in .env file to default value (Laravel). try it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already configured headers and it still doesn't work, try creating a new key:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data: _token: '{{csrf_token()}}',
```